# Lubuntu 13.10 - can't install VMware tools

Tags: vmware-server, vmware-tools

Some days ago I installed Lubuntu 13.10 (on VMware Server). Now I want to install vmware-tools, but after running `./vmware-install.pl -d`, I get:

```
The following VMware kernel modules have been found on your system that were not installed by the VMware Installer. Please remove them then run this installer again.
vmci
I.e. - 'rm /lib/modules/3.11.0-12-generic/misc/<ModuleName>.{o,ko*}"
```

Any idea what can I do?

Comment: Did you follow the suggestion in the error message?

Comment: I am a noob, so I don't have a xxxx to delete kernel modules. Is it safe to do it? And yes - they are not on the suggested locations, but a little deeper in directory structure?