# vmware tools installation problem

Tags: vmware-tools

I just installed XUbuntu on my Vmware Workstation.
After I saw, that I can't change display settings (resolution), I try to install VMware Tools. But - after I run `vmware-install.pl`, I get a message:

```
The following VMware kernel modules have been found on your system that were 
not installed by the VMware Installer. Please remove them then run this
installer again.

vmci
Execution aborted.
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 4):

This is what I did for Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo apt remove --auto-remove open-vm-tools
sudo apt purge open-vm-tools
```

It complained about not being able to delete a directory since it is not empty so I manually removed one file that resides in that directory using:

```
sudo rm /etc/vmware-tools/scripts/vmware/network.old.0
```

And now you can run vmware-install.pl again.

Comment: I had to completely get rid of the /etc/vmware-tools folder, then I could use vmware-install.sh ...

Comment: This procedure worked for 17.04 too.  @firepol, I left that folder there and it seemed to work fine.

Comment: Btw. is there an option to manually download the installation files? Because my option to deliver them from VMware is greyed out, and for Windows its easy to find a manual download

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.  You need to run the command with the `./`, so just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo ./vmware-install.pl
```

Also see if open-vm-tools are installed.  Remove with the below command

```
sudo apt-get remove open-vm-tools
```

As a last resort, delete the `.vmware` folder from your home folder, reboot your machine, and try installing vmware tools again.

**Edit**

Try the following command: `sudo /usr/bin/vmware-config.pl`

Comment: I did ... before (and now again). Now I even reinstall the system (with disk format), but the same problem again.

Comment: Try what I've added in my answer.  Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thans for help. I tried remove open-vm-tools, but it wasn't installed. The (hidden) .vmware folder also wasn't there.

Comment: What version vmware workstation are you trying to install, and Ubuntu release?

Comment: XUbuntu 14.04 64-bit and VMware Server 2.0.2

Comment: After my memory starts to work, I found my previous question from some months ago: http://askubuntu.com/questions/363601/lubuntu-13-10-cant-install-vmware-tools - it looks, that I have the same problem before with different version of Linux. So the problem is probably in Vmware Server.

Comment: Did you install linux-headers, and build-essential xinetd prior to installing vmware?  And see the edit in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't found /usr/bin/vmware-config.pl ... it isn't there. I didn't install linux-headers (and build-essential xinetd) - I simply don't know, how to do it. I installed a virtual machine and try to install Vmware Tools as usually.

Comment: Any idea? Or maybe Mitch - how can I install essentials ...

Comment: `sudo apt-get install build-essential xinetd linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Comment: Tnx for answer. But the same error occurred. Now I give my hands up.